# Getting problem in connecting VPN in azure

Tags: azure, cloud, vpn, connect, rdp

trying to connect VPN in azure through RDP option. Unable to connect. Not clear how to enter credential to connect.

Answer (score 0):

enter credential like this
eg.

**UserName**: LocalAccount\username

**Password**: password

Here username and password will be same as you mentioned at the time of creating VM.